# How to generate plot row count per time period of time series SQL data in plotly more efficiently?

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, plotly, clickhouse

I have a timeseries table with two columns, datetime and value.
I want to generate a chart of number of rows versus time period.

So I have implemented it (in Python) using a loop between the start and end dates and a  `SELECT COUNT(*)` . Incrementing the time period by 30 minutes per iteration and saving the counts out to a local array which is then plotted on a Scatter chart.

It works well. But I feel that SQL queries in a loop is poor design due to hitting the database with rapid repeat queries.

Is there a better way ? Possibly implementing the loop inside the SQL engine (postgres in this case) ? Or is there a magic SQL 'count of rows versus time' utility ?

I have also implemented the same for a ClickHouseDB time series table.

```
# Y M D
start_date = dt.datetime(2022, 7, 5)
  
# to Y M D
end_date = dt.datetime(2022, 7, 8)
  
# delta time
delta = dt.timedelta(minutes=30)
  
y = []
x = []
# iterate over range of dates
while (start_date <= end_date):
    time_to = start_date + delta
    queryStr = f'''select '{start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")}' as date, count(*) as count from my_packet_table 
                 WHERE datetime 
                 BETWEEN '{start_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")}'  
                 AND     '{time_to.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")}'  '''
    result = pd.read_sql_query(queryStr, cnx) #.to_dict()
    start_date += delta
    if (len(result)) > 0:
        y.append(int(result.iloc[0][1]))
        x_date = dt.datetime.strptime( result.iloc[0][0], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        x.append(x_date )

scatter = plotly.graph_objs.Scatter(x=x, y=y, mode = 'markers+lines')
layout = plotly.graph_objs.Layout(xaxis={'type': 'date', 
                                         'tick0': x[0], 
                                         'tickmode': 'linear', 
                                         'dtick': 86400000.0 / 12 }) # 2 hrs
fig = plotly.graph_objs.Figure(data=[scatter], layout=layout)
plotly.offline.iplot(fig)
```

The resulting plot looks like this. Title: 'Number of packets received per 30 minute time period by date/time '
[image]

Comment: Your instinct is right. You basically need to generate a resultset of dates at even increments, and then you have something to outer join from. This is called a datespine.  Some RDBMS have a helper function to help you with this, others require you to write a CTE that is recursive. Does your version support GENERATE_SERIES() ?

Comment: The datespine I mentioned is useful and necessary when your increment might have 0 counts in them. Your chart indicates plenty of data within each timeslice, so you might just use date_trunc on the timestamp, and then GROUP BY that and be done w/ it.

Comment: Thanks Josh, yes postgres does support GENERATE_SERIES. Thanks for the datespine pointers which I will investigate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick answer that will get you what you want (I think).

The only danger of doing it this way, is that you will not get a row if you have 0 rows in the 30-minute interval. The way to solve that would be a datespine, which is more complicated and would require you to use `GENERATE_SERIES()`

Since you appear to have enough data so that every slot has at least 1 row, you can get away with a simpler approach that truncates the date and then does a `GROUP BY` aggregate.

A query like:

```
/* if you know that timeslices won't have zero counts, then you can date_trunc and aggregate */
WITH TRUNCATED AS (
  SELECT date_trunc('hour', "POSITION_DATE") AS hour_stump, 
    (extract(minute FROM "POSITION_DATE"):: int / 30) AS minute_slot, * 
  FROM posdata
), 
COMBINED_STAMP AS (
  SELECT hour_stump + (minute_slot || ' minutes'):: interval AS my_interval, * 
  FROM TRUNCATED
) 
SELECT 
  my_interval, count(1) AS obs_count
FROM COMBINED_STAMP 
GROUP BY my_interval 
ORDER BY my_interval;
```

If this doesn't quite work, it's because I didnt have data to properly test this with. I used F1 racing data which comes in milliseconds so I mentally tried to adjust my query to work in your 30 minute situation.

If it doesn't work, please add some sample data and I can continue helping.